# Determine the MAX of avg(col) in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, subquery

I have a table as follows:

```
year                    int                                        
month                   int                                        
dayofmonth              int                                        
deptime                 int                                        
uniquecarrier           string                                     
flightnum               int                                        
arrdelay                int                                        
origin                  string                                     
dest                    string
```

I want to get the destination airport (dest) where the average arrival delay (arrdelay) is the highest.

I want to avoid something crude like what I currently have:

```
select dest, avg(arrdelay) as average from flightdelays GROUP BY dest ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I've tried all sorts of things but nothing works thus far. I can actually get the maximum average time itself:

```
select MAX(avgtime) from (SELECT dest as destination, avg(arrdelay) as avgtime FROM flightdelays GROUP BY dest) as maxdelay;
```

but modifying this won't work - it just won't allow me to select the destination from the above.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean crude regarding your first query ? Is it that you want the 'dest' only and not the value of the average ?

If so, consider using an additional select :

```
select dest from (select dest, avg(arrdelay) as average from flightdelays GROUP BY dest ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Hive doesn't allow to use a 'group by' or 'order by' with a field that is not in your select statement, however Mysql for instance does.